# Function to find duplicate (2d) cells in a 3d array

Tags: c

`int duplicate (int cards[5][4][13])`

I have been trying to develop a function (the prototype is above) that loops through a 3d array that holds 5 cards of a hand and the numerical index to a cell that holds a 1 indicating that a card exists is based on the suit (4) and the face (13).

For example if in a hypothetical hand the first card was a seven of clubs its index would be: [1][3][7] where 1 is the card 3 = clubs and 7 = sevens.

I need to loop through all five cards in the hand and find out if there are any two cards that are identical.

I cant figure out how to do this because I could compare the index of the first card to the other four but then the remaining cards wouldnt be compared to each other.

The function returns 1 if there is a duplicate or 0 if not.

I am very confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to loop over every possible *card*, and count how many times it appears:

```
int suit;

for (suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
    int rank;

    for (rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++) {
        int count = 0;
        int card;

        for (card = 0; card < 5; card++) {
            count += cards[card][suit][rank];
        }

        if (count > 1)
            return 1;
    }
}

return 0;
```

---

However, the data structure you've chosen isn't very efficient.  To find out what card N is, you need to search through all of `cards[N][0..3][0..12]` to find the 1.  A better approach would be to use a `struct`:

```
struct card {
    int suit; /* 0..3 */
    int rank; /* 0..12 */
};

struct card cards[5];
```

This will be a lot easier to work with.  For example, to find duplicates, you'd just need to check if any of the other cards had the same `rank` and `suit` values:

```
int card1, card2;

for (card1 = 0; card1 < 5; card1++)
    for (card2 = card1 + 1, card2 < 5; card2++)
        if (cards[card1].suit == cards[card2].suit && cards[card1].rank == cards[card2].rank)
            return 1;
return 0;
```

Comment: Here is an example of my thinking:
card1: cards[1][3][7], 
card3: cards[3][3][7]. 

They are different cards but they are identical.

Comment: So you wish to find out if there is an identical card in a *different* hand?

Comment: Within the hand. cards might be more appropriately named hands in this case. of the 5 card in this hand i am looking for two that are idenctical.

Comment: Here's what's wrong with your data structure: let's say Billy's eyes are blue. Would you say that he has blue eyes? That sounds natural, right? But your array approach is analogous to saying that the blueness of Billy's eyes is true, the brownness is false, the greenness is false and the greyness is false. Use arrays to collect several logical "things" together, and use raw data to represent the attributes of a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing a hand which is a collection of 5 (hopefully unique) cards.  that means you want 5 objects.  But `cards[5][4][13]` is 260 objects.  That would be for a structure with 5 slots, and each slot can contain any quantity of any type of card.

Since I suspect that's what you really want, I'll advise you to change your representation of a hand to `int cards[5]`.  In each position in `cards` you'll place an integer 0-12 for each card in the suit of hearts, 13-25 for each card in the suit of spades, and so on for clubs and diamonds.  If you also need a way to represent no card in that slot, you could use -1.

The checking for duplicates is easy, just compare each integer value in the hand.